# vCenter not functioning after changing subnet

Tags: ldap, vmware, esxi, vcenter

Last week, I changed my whole subnet from 192.168.1.1/24 to 10.0.0.0/8. One of the machines I had to adjust the IP addresses on was my server, running ESXI and a vCenter instance on top. I changed all their IP addresses through the config CLI, but since then I get the following error when I go to vCenter's IP address:

```
503 Service Unavailable (Failed to connect to endpoint: [N7Vmacore4Http20NamedPipeServiceSpecE:0x000055f910c3eed0] _serverNamespace = / action = Allow _pipeName =/var/run/vmware/vpxd-webserver-pipe)
```

*Note:* ESXI is working as aspected.

After digging into vCenter's logs, I found the following in `/var/log/vmware/vpxd-svcs/vpxd-svcs.log`:

```
2020-02-26T07:49:14.205Z [main  INFO  com.vmware.cis.lotus.LotusLocator  opId=] vmAfClient.getDomainControllerEx("") : 192.168.1.122
2020-02-26T07:49:14.205Z [main  INFO  com.vmware.cis.lotus.LotusLocator  opId=] Lotus hostname URL : 192.168.1.122
2020-02-26T07:49:14.208Z [main  INFO  com.vmware.cis.lotus.LotusLocator  opId=] vmAfClient.getDomainName() in baseDn format : dc=vsphere,dc=local
2020-02-26T07:49:14.214Z [main  INFO  com.vmware.cis.lotus.LotusLocator  opId=] Successfully refreshed machine account credentials
2020-02-26T07:49:21.164Z [refresh-lotus-locator-task  INFO  com.vmware.cis.lotus.LotusLocator  opId=] vmAfClient.getDomainControllerEx("") : 192.168.1.122
2020-02-26T07:49:21.164Z [refresh-lotus-locator-task  INFO  com.vmware.cis.lotus.LotusLocator  opId=] Lotus hostname URL : 192.168.1.122
2020-02-26T07:49:21.175Z [refresh-lotus-locator-task  INFO  com.vmware.cis.lotus.LotusLocator  opId=] vmAfClient.getDomainName() in baseDn format : dc=vsphere,dc=local
2020-02-26T07:49:21.194Z [refresh-lotus-locator-task  INFO  com.vmware.cis.lotus.LotusLocator  opId=] Successfully refreshed machine account credentials
2020-02-26T07:49:44.238Z [main  WARN  com.vmware.identity.interop.ldap.LdapErrorChecker  opId=] Error received by LDAP client: com.vmware.identity.interop.ldap.OpenLdapClientLibrary, error code: -1
2020-02-26T07:49:44.238Z [main  ERROR com.vmware.cis.lotus.LdapUtils  opId=] Failed to connect to LDAP; uri: ldap://192.168.1.122:389
2020-02-26T07:49:44.239Z [main  WARN  com.vmware.cis.lotus.LdapConnectionFactory  opId=] Failed to connect to LDAP server at 192.168.1.122, will retry; attempt:11 of 15, delay:5 sec
```

As you can see, the IP address is still the old one.

What can I do to change this? I already tried changing the IP addresses in `/etc/vmware-vpx/vpxd.cfg` but to no avail...

Or would I be better off deploying a new vCenter instance?

**System specs:**

- VMware VirtualCenter 6.7.0 build-13007421
- ESXI Client version: 1.33.3
- ESXI Client build number: 12923304
- ESXi version: 6.7.0
- ESXi build number: 13006603

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was not able to change the IP address of the vCenter instance because that functionality was only added recently in Update 3 ([see this comment on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vmware/comments/f9rxdb/vcenter_not_functioning_after_changing_subnet/fitkmn1/)).

To fix the problem I simply deployed a new vCenter instance, added the host and its VM's and voilà, everything is working again.